# Badge briefing may not be correct

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, grammar

This is how the **Caucus** badge is defined:

> Visited an election during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote

I think this should be:

> Visited an election during any phase of an active election and **had** enough reputation to cast a vote

If we use the past tense in the first part of the sentence, in this case we should use the same tense in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

Will be there in the next build.